# Remove controller_name from URL in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

> My Url is  http://www.example.com/players/playersdetail/100006   i
>   have a players controller. I need to remove or hide controller and
>   method name (players/playersdetail) from url and i want name in place
>   of id(100006)

1. Ex- http://www.example.com/gagan-gupta
2. Ex- http://www.example.com/gagan-gupta/about
3. Ex- https://www.facebook.com/gagan-gupta/friends

How to achieve in Ruby On Rails?

**Routes is**

```
Something::Application.routes.draw do
      get "players/search"
      post "players/search"
      get "players/playerslist"
      get "players/playersdetail"
      get "players/list"
      get "players/followers"
      get "players/following"    
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Your::Application.routes.draw do
  scope ":name" do
    get '', to: 'players#show'
    get :about, to 'players#about'
    get :friends, to 'players#friends
  end
end
```

[Reference](http://pivotallabs.com/single-resource-rest-rails-routes/)

Answer (score 1):

Your routes.rb something like this:

```
resources :players
```

which produces routes of the `form /entries/24225252/foo`.

There exists a :path argument that allows you to use something besides the default name entries. For example:

```
resources :players, :path => 'my-cool-path'
```

will produce routes of the form `/my-cool-path/2012/05/10/foo.`

But, if we pass an empty string to :path, we see the behaviour you're looking for:

```
resources :players, :path => ''
```

will produce routes of the form `/2012/05/10/foo.`

**Also another option:**

```
  get ':year/:month/:day/:title' => 'some_controller#show', :as => 'players'
  put ':year/:month/:day/:title/edit' => 'some_controller#edit', :as => 'edit_players'
  delete ':year/:month/:day/:title' => 'some_controller#destroy', :as => 'destroy_players'
```